# Should I remove "service" suffix from Angular services class names?

Tags: angular, angularjs

When we generate a new service in Angular using the `ng generate service` command, Angular automatically adds the suffix "Service" to the name of my class.

For example:

`ng generate service message` generates a file named "message.service.ts", with a MessageService class

So I wondered whether it was good practice to remove this suffix (**in class name**), as it's obvious that it's a service (it's mentioned in the file name, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the "Service" suffix in the class name when generating a service is considered a good practice in Angular. This convention provides clarity and readability, as it immediately indicates that the file represents a service. It also promotes consistency across projects, making it easier for developers to understand the structure and purpose of files within an Angular project. Additionally, maintaining a consistent naming convention for services aids in the maintainability of larger projects by facilitating the location and management of services. While it's possible to deviate from this convention, it's generally recommended to follow it to ensure consistency and clarity in Angular projects.